# Execute command in AWS EKS using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

We have an EKS that is using Role base access control. So there is a specific role through which that EKS can be accessed. I am trying to run a command inside that EKS using AWS Lambda. Currently I have give administrator access to AWS Lambda but it not able to access EKS because EKS is using another role to allow access. The programming language of Lambda is not a barrier for me so either Python or nodejs will work.

Can any one of you suggest me what I am doing wrong. Any tutorial or doc will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You must edit the aws-auth configmap to provide additional IAM roles access to query your EKS cluster's API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: @jordanm there is already a role EKSrole which has access to AWS EKS. In console and cli we have to assume that role to access EKS even if we have admin access. If I assign this EKSrole to lambda then it will be able to access EKS and run commands there?

Comment: Lambda execution role requires slightly different trust policy. I would highly advise against sharing roles in that way.

Comment: @jordanm so what is the best practice here? If i assign the same role to lambda will it not work or its simply not a best practice?

Comment: Make a new role for the lambda and add it to your aws-auth configmap.